# Why first click event of button not working

Tags: c#, multithreading, task, dotnet-httpclient, multitasking

I have app(net4.7.2) like this:
[image: app screen 1]

*Program is simple, when user presses OK, im sending request to [steam market](https://steamcommunity.com/market/) to get informations about item which user entered (item steam market url) to textbox.*

But when im trying to send request, first click event of button not working:
[image: app screen 2]

**Code of OK button:**

```
    private void btnOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtItemURL.Text.StartsWith("https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/") == true)
        {
            Helpers.Helper.BuildURL(txtItemURL.Text);

            SteamMarketItem SMI = Helpers.Helper.GetItemDetails();
            lblPrice.Text = SMI.LowestPrice.ToString() + "$";
            pbItemImage.ImageLocation = SMI.ImagePath;

            Helpers.Helper.Kontrollar_BerpaEt();
        }
        else
        {
            Helpers.Helper.Kontrollar_SifirlaYanlisDaxilEdilib();
        }
    }
```

**Method GetItemDetails():**

```
    public static SteamMarketItem GetItemDetails()
    {
        WinForms.Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;

        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            try
            {
                using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
                {
                    JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

                    /* Get item info: */
                    var ResultFromEndpoint1 = client.GetAsync(ReadyEndpointURL1).Result;
                    var Json1 = ResultFromEndpoint1.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                    dynamic item = serializer.Deserialize<object>(Json1);
                    marketItem.LowestPrice = float.Parse(((string)item["lowest_price"]).Replace("$", "").Replace(".", ","));

                    /* Get item image: */
                    var ResultFromEndpoint2 = client.GetAsync(ReadyEndPointURL2).Result;
                    var Json2 = ResultFromEndpoint2.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                    var html = ((dynamic)serializer.Deserialize<object>(Json2))["results_html"];

                    HtmlDocument htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
                    htmlDoc.LoadHtml(html);
                    marketItem.ImagePath = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//img[@class='market_listing_item_img']").Attributes["src"].Value + ".png";

                    Kontrollar_BerpaEt();
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                Kontrollar_SifirlaYanlisDaxilEdilib();
            }
        });

        return marketItem;
    }
```

**Class SteamMarketItem:**

```
public class SteamMarketItem
{
    public string ImagePath { get; set; }
    public float LowestPrice { get; set; }
}
```

**When im using Task.Run() first click not working, without Task.Run() working + but main UI thread stopping when request not finished.**

I have no idea why this happens, I cant find problem fix myself, I will be glad to get help from you. Thanks.

Comment: Note: You are not just LISTENING, since you're sending a request. Just a little nit lol

Comment: haha, yea u true, but i will add some functionalities, like listening price of some items which user will add to listview (like im planning to send request with 5 second interval and notify user if new lower price created).. and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `async` you need to change your event handler to `async` so you can use `await`, please see the following:

**1.** Change your Event handler to `async void`, `async void` is acceptable on event handler methods, you should try to use `async Task` in place of `async void` in most other cases, so change your method signature to the following:

```
   private async void btnOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
        if (txtItemURL.Text.StartsWith("https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/") == true)
        {
            Helpers.Helper.BuildURL(txtItemURL.Text);
            //here we use await to await the task   
            SteamMarketItem SMI = await Helpers.Helper.GetItemDetails();
            lblPrice.Text = SMI.LowestPrice.ToString() + "$";
            pbItemImage.ImageLocation = SMI.ImagePath;

            Helpers.Helper.Kontrollar_BerpaEt();
        }
        else
        {
            Helpers.Helper.Kontrollar_SifirlaYanlisDaxilEdilib();
        }
   }
```

**2.** You shouldn't need to use `Task.Run`, `HttpClient` exposes `async` methods and you can make the method `async`, also, calling `.Result` to block on an `async` method is typically not a good idea and you should make the enclosing method `async` so you can utilize `await`:

```
   //Change signature to async and return a Task<T>
   public async static Task<SteamMarketItem> GetItemDetails()
   {
       WinForms.Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;
       //what is marketItem?? Where is it declared?
       try
       {
           using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
           {
               JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

                /* Get item info: */
                var ResultFromEndpoint1 = await client.GetAsync(ReadyEndpointURL1);
                var Json1 = await ResultFromEndpoint1.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                dynamic item = serializer.Deserialize<object>(Json1);
                marketItem.LowestPrice = float.Parse(((string)item["lowest_price"]).Replace("$", "").Replace(".", ","));

                /* Get item image: */
                var ResultFromEndpoint2 = await client.GetAsync(ReadyEndPointURL2);
                var Json2 = await ResultFromEndpoint2.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                var html = ((dynamic)serializer.Deserialize<object>(Json2))["results_html"];

                HtmlDocument htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
                htmlDoc.LoadHtml(html);
                marketItem.ImagePath = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//img[@class='market_listing_item_img']").Attributes["src"].Value + ".png";

                Kontrollar_BerpaEt();
           }
       }
       catch
       {
            Kontrollar_SifirlaYanlisDaxilEdilib();
       }
       //what is marketItem?? Where is it declared?
       return marketItem;
   }
```

Comment: thanks for trying to help. This way blocking main ui thread :(

Comment: @zeroG It won't block the main thread. If you followed my example code. Otherwise you have some other piece of code you didn't share that is blocking the UI thread.

Comment: Form1.cs : https://pastebin.com/xDLtem7B
Helper.cs : https://pastebin.com/JSuMuS5X
SteamMarketItem.cs : Added to this ticket.

Comment: @zeroG You used my original version of my answer, I had missed a line of code where you were using `.Result`, please change your source code in method `GetItemDetails`, from `var ResultFromEndpoint1 = client.GetAsync(ReadyEndpointURL1).Result;` to `var ResultFromEndpoint1 = await client.GetAsync(ReadyEndpointURL1);`

Comment: thanks, now ready, working normal right now. Thanks for taking time to help.